# AG-GRID not showing field as a Checkbox when Value is Boolean and Model Type is 'serverSide'

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

Working well when the model is default, the data Client Side Data, the field shows a checkbox when value is boolean, but when i change to Server Side Data, shows true or false, if I tried to edit it in the table it shows the default checkbox.

This is my gridOptions.

```
    const gridOptions = {
        rowHeight: 50,
        columnDefs: columnDefs,
        defaultColDef: {
            flex: 1,
            minWidth: 100,
            sortable: true,
            resizable: true,
        },

        pagination: true,
        paginationPageSize: 250,
        rowModelType: 'serverSide'
    };
```

This is my columndef for that field, notice that i tried to force the value boolean with no success.. The value is already boolean.

```
                {
            field: 'active',
            headerName: 'Active',
            editable: true,
            cellEditor: 'agCheckboxCellEditor'

            // valueGetter: (params) => {
            //  return Boolean(params.data.active);
            // }
        }
```